# How to pick max/mins of elements that match patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a list of complicated expressions that involve indexed coefficients.  For example:

```
expr={m[5],c[3]*m[1]^2+m[2],Sqrt[m[2]+3*m[3]*c[8],foo[m[3]*m[5]]};
```

How can I find the largest m index that appears in each list element?  The outpoot I'd like to see is:

```
maxIndex[expr]

(*  {5,2,3,5}   *)
```

Note that the m[q_]'s might appear inside functions, such as Sqrt[] and foo[].

Comment: Your `expr` has a typo; please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you want:

```
expr = {m[5], c[3]*m[1]^2 + m[2], Sqrt[m[2] + 3*m[3]*c[8]], foo[m[3]*m[5]]};

Max @ Cases[#, m[n_] :> n, {0, -1}] & /@ expr
```

> ```
> {5, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

With an operator form of `Map`:

```
maxIndex = Map[Max @ Cases[#, m[n_] :> n, {0, -1}] &];

maxIndex[expr]
```

> ```
> {5, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

Comment: Perfection!  Thank you.